# How can I force django to restart a database connection from the shell?

Tags: python, django

I have a django project on a remote server. From my local machine, I connect to the database through ssh:

```
ssh -L 63333:localhost:5432 me@my.server
```

And change my local settings.py as:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 63333
    }
}
```

And on a Jupyter QtConsole on my local machine, I follow these steps for setup:

```
import os
import django
os.chdir('/path/to/my/project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'
django.setup()
```

It all works fine until my ssh connection is broken by some reason. First I get this error (on a line that queries the database, say, `my_model.objects.first()`):

```
DatabaseErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/ayhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args)
     84             else:
---> 85                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     86 

DatabaseError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

When I reconnect through ssh, I keep getting the following error:

```
InterfaceErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
/home/ayhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in _cursor(self, name)
    233         with self.wrap_database_errors:
--> 234             return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
    235 

/home/ayhan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py in create_cursor(self, name)
    211         else:
--> 212             cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    213         cursor.tzinfo_factory = utc_tzinfo_factory if settings.USE_TZ else None

InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

The error only goes away if I restart the IPython kernel. I tried executing the same steps for the setup. I also tried `from importlib import reload; reload(django)` and then doing the setup again but it gives the same error no matter what.

Sometimes this happens while I have variables that I don't want to lose in the memory so I want to avoid restarting the kernel. Is there a way to recreate the database connection without it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
from django.db import connections
conn = connections['default']
conn.connect()
```

or

```
from django.db import connection
connection.connect()
```

Comment: If you're not sure if your connection has been dropped, you can call `connection.connect()` regardless and it shouldn't cause a problem. For example, after a very long running celery task to log completion

Answer (score 9):

```
from django.db import connections, connection
for conn in connections.all():
    conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
```

then call connection.cursor will get a fresh connection,
django source code:

```
def _cursor(self, name=None):
    self.ensure_connection()
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
        return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
```

Comment: conn.close_if_unusable_or_obsolete()
--- This code part was very useful for me. Thank's a LOT!

Comment: It seems that there is a function for exactly this now: `close_old_connections()`. It is attached to a signal so it will be triggered automatically for WSGI/ASGI requests, but if you might still call it manually in e.g. a command.